# Deployment of EAR file on Websphere 8.5.5.x server

Tags: java, websphere, java-6

I have an ear file written in java and and is deployed on WAS 6.1. This ear file contains java code written in 1.4. Now there is upgraade on WAS to 8.5.5.x where in i have to deploy this ear file on it. Will it work on was 8.5.5.x . Do we have to make any changes to have it worked on was 8.5.5.x.And what version of jre and jdk does 8.5.5.x supports.Please advice..     Also what are the precautions to be taken to move the code to WAS 8.5.5.x without any issues

Comment: simple google search gives this table - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005002

Comment: i need to know will the java code written in 1.4 work fine on WAS 8.5.5.x

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not your application will run on a new release of an application server is not exactly a programming question for this site.  However, my advice would be to look at the WebSphere Migration Toolkit, then simply "try it and see".

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/

Comment: a doubt is a doubt.. where to ask then

Comment: I agree with you. But you have to do your homework a little, tried your options and ask your question, instead of just a question. Sometimes these guys are just mean even with all the relevant information provided in question.

Answer (score 0):

The advice given in the preceding answer is the same as what I advise. Java code compiled using an earlier JDK will work fine.  If the application is unchanged it should deploy without problem.

Some care is needed to make sure the application really is unchanged.  For example, if the application is exported from a development environment and that environment has been updates to a higher JavaEE level, that can update the schema version of exported descriptors, and that can have impacts.  But if the application archive (the EAR file) is exactly the same as was deployed to the earlier edition of the application server, that EAR should deploy to the newer edition of the application server.

There can be differences to application function because of the deployment to a higher level application server edition.  The higher level edition of the server implements a higher level version of JavaEE specifications, and these can sometimes cause application function to work differently.  You will need to consult IBM WebSphere Application Server documentation (the migration toolkit link, above, is a good place to start) to determine if this will occur with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check out the WebSphere Application Server Migration Toolkit, downloadable for free from wasdev.net. It will identify migration issues going from Java 1.4 to 1.6, as well as any deprecations, removals, or behavior changes going from WebSphere 6.1 to 8.5.5.x. It even provides quick fixes for many of the issues.

Comment: After downloading the migration tool kit , what has to be done

Comment: You have to install it in your Eclipse, and import your ear to run analysis against it. There is pdf documentation available on the same page you download the toolkit from that gives step by step instructions.

Comment: Do i have to directly import the ear file or import the project workspace

Comment: Is there any other way to check apart from downloading any software migration kit .. Any website or so

Comment: You can import the ear file, or the project workspace if you previously exported it somewhere. I do not know of any website that will analyze your application for WebSphere version to version migration issues.